# Google drive api rest upload file with service account not works

Tags: javascript, api, drive

After creating a service account from the google iam console, and having obtained the json with the private_key,client_email and so on... I have problems integrating them into my javascript code to upload a file to google drive with an authentication server to server. With the use of nodejs I didn't have any problem (I used JWTtoken), I would be grateful if you could help me to insert the authentication parameters correctly in the javascript post request code of the example.

```
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files",
        data:{
            uploadType:"multipart",
            parents: ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        async: true,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        Authorization: ????????????????? <---
        processData: false,
        timeout: 60000
    });
};
```

When I try to do to update this file I see no result. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to use Service Account? Because when I saw your script, I thought that you might want to use OAuth2 process. Can you show us about the script of Node.js which worked fine as a sample script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks, It is possible to use an Account service via Rest to upload a file in google drive? Can you show me a guide/example to use a Service Account? In the doc https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth I have difficult to find this approach.

Comment: For example, when I searched ``javascript drive api service account`` at Google, the following thread can be found. Is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/428

Answer (score 0):

Add contentType: false inside $.ajax function.

Add your file in the data object inside ajax call. You should use FormData object like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', $('.file-input')[0].files[0]);
```

and then set data: formData inside $.ajax function

Comment: No change, I think that is an authentication problem

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file), if you're using alt=media, you need to make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's [resource URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and include the query parameter alt=media.

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
>   Authorization: Bearer
>   ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#examples) the examples of performing a file download with our Drive API client libraries.

> String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M"; 
>   OutputStream
>   outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>   driveService.files().get(fileId)
>           .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream)

Get the File id and pass it through the function to upload the file